# Calling a class bool function

Tags: c++

I have defined a public bool function in a class.  When I create an object instance of this class and type a dot after it, a list of class functions appears, so I select the bool function I want.  But when I define a bool variable and make it equal to the return of the bool function, the compiler complains about an unused variable.

My question is, where is the error?

Note: when I create the class, there wasn't any error in either `class.h` or `class.cpp`.

The user `program.cpp` is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: note :  in class.h  i've defined this bool function as :
bool insertitem (const listelemtype e , const int l )

and in class.cpp  i declared it as :  
bool inord_list:: insertitem (const listelemtype e , const int l )
{
my code
}

Comment: Please prefer to add your code as a [mcve] into the question as _code_, not as images. Some people can't see images, screen writers can't interpret them, and their links die which means this question will become useless to somebody in the future

Comment: I'm not sure what is hard to understand about "unused variable"? You have a variable and you are not using it.

Comment: @immibis , my question is how the variable is unused althought i pass a  bool function that returns true or false to it .

Comment: @user288086 After storing the value in the variable the program never does anything with that value. There is no point having a variable that holds a value if the program never looks at the value in it.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is a *warning*, not an *error*.
2. It is warning you that you have defined a variable `bool insert` that you are not using for anything after the assignment (See your second picture).

Comment: Remy Lebeau , how i not use it while i put the result of 
x.insertitem(word,l) to it ?

Comment: After you assign the return value to the variable, you are not using the variable anymore for anything else. The variable is useless.  That is what the compiler is warning about.